# Minimal production Django server on Windows

Tags: django, windows

I need to deploy a small Django app to be used in a small intranet. Concurrency and speed are non issues because there will be, at most, 10 users (and I bet that there will be almost no concurrency).

There is already a MySQL server. The problem is with the Django app. What is the most lightwieght server I can install under a WinXP environment ? The Apache + mod_python approach seems a little overkill. The cherrypy server seems more suitable.

Any suggestions ? Someone with similar experiences ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use IIS with [PyISAPIe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyISAPIe/1.0.130).

I outline [my Django on Windows deployment here](http://brianbondy.com/blog/id/79/the-new-site-is-out) and also [more info on PyISAPIe with Python 2.6 here](http://brianbondy.com/blog/id/80/pyisapie-with-django-11-and-python-26).

Answer (score 2):

As I'm not a big fan of IIS, I'd still use Apache + mod_wsgi. mod_wsgi is officially recommended way of deploying django apps, according to http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

We're currently deploying a small intranet Django app to complement a closed source app on IIS to an audience of about 300-400, but low use.

We opted for cherrypy by means of [django-wsgiserver](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-wsgiserve), but go for the [bitbucket version](https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/django-wsgiserver/) if you don't use the admin, there's a bug in the 0.6.10 version that's on pypi.

We have IIS as a reverse proxy in front of it, and use media from the existing app. Don't know yet if it's stable, but I like the fact that it's conceptually the same as the Apache+gunicorn setup that I use on the *nix box.

Since this question dates from 2 years, I'm very curious about your experience.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows port of [lighttpd](http://en.wlmp-project.net/downloads.php) also bears mention.